# Setting NavigationBar's title asynchronously

Tags: react-native, redux, navigationbar, navigator

I am trying to set a `NavigationBar` for my `Navigator`. When I display a static title, it is OK. However, when I try to set title asynchronously (for example when I go to user's profile route, I get user's display name from API and set `this.props.navigation.title` when API call promise resolves) the title gets jumpy.

What would be the proper approach for this issue?

Here is my component (which is connected to redux store) that handles `NavigationBar`:

```
import React from 'react-native';
let {
    Component,
    Navigator,
    View
} = React;

import {connect} from 'react-redux';

let NavigationBarRouteMapper = {
    Title: (route, navigator, index, navState) => {
        return (
            <Text style={{marginTop: 15, fontSize: 18, color: colors.white}}>{this.props.navigation.title}</Text>
        );
    }
};

class App extends Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <View style={{flex: 1}}>
                <Navigator
                    ref={'navigator'}
                    configureScene={...}
                    navigationBar={
                        <Navigator.NavigationBar routeMapper={ NavigationBarRouteMapper } />
                    }
                    renderScene={(route, navigator) => {...}}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default connect(state => state)(App);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `routeMapper` is a stateless object and `route` seems to be the only way (best practice) to keep the state of `NavigationBar`.

`route` can be set with `this.props.navigator.replace(newRoute);` in child components. However, this will re-`renderScene` and will sometimes cause dead loop of reRendering child components. What we want is to change the NavigationBar itself without side effects.

Luckily, there's a way to keep the context of current route. Like this:

```
var route = this.props.navigator.navigationContext.currentRoute;
route.headerItems = {title: "Message"};
this.props.navigator.replace(route);
```

Refs:

- [How to change the title of the NavigatorIOS without changing the route in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30829976/how-to-change-the-title-of-the-navigatorios-without-changing-the-route-in-react)
- [[Navigator] Binding the navigation bar with the underlying scene](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/2615)